# What is Gorochana or Goulochan?

Tags: worship, tilak

I have Gorochana or Goulochan, given by a friend. I want to know it's vedic application.

I have two types of Goulochan one is from cows head and other one cow gallstone Bezoar.

I did not find anywhere in web or in any magazine. Only through Durga Saptasati book its written to make tabiz with this Gouloachan.

Can I make tilak and give it to God while worshiping ?

Please give some details information and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Important use of Gorochana is to put on forehead as **Tilak**.

This Tilak gives positive energy and helps to accomplish the delayed work promptly, removes obstacles from the way and protects from all the bad energies of surroundings.

> Can I make tilak and give it to God while worshipping ?

I don't think so. This tilak is used by ourselves only.

---

It is also assumed a source of valuable medicine. People  use it in both ways internally as well as externally in healing of various common diseases.

---

Additional information (Don't know about it's genuineness):

Gorochana is also used for Vashikaran purpose. It is also used to carry out any work without hurdle, if any work is getting prevented due to some reasons, it is very helpful and works well in that regard , to overcome obstacles and avoid delay in progress and get achievements.

---

See more information in [this link](http://kamiyasindoor.com/Original-Gorochana.html).

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources for your answer.